# Where does Office for Mac store the user personalization information?

Tags: ms-office

I am managing a number of Mac computers where I would like my users to not need to manually set their name.

This name is used when creating lock files on network shares. If it is unset, then the lock file is created with the name of "Microsoft Office user", which is not helpful when trying to identify the person who has a file open. Additionally, in this environment, computers are often shared without being completely reimaged, so this name, even when set, is often wrong.

It would be useful if I could modify the saved user name from outside of office, since I have MDM control of the computers.

Where specifically is this name stored?

Comment: What version of office? And your OS?